# Is the speed of light the ultimate speed limit?

Tags: cosmology, universe, big-bang, faster-than-light, space-expansion

As we all know nothing can go faster than the speed of light as mentioned by most of our pioneer's in physics. But as I was listening to one of the statements of Sir. Stephen Hawkins he stated that at the time of big bang the universe expanded to about a thousand light years in just few trillionth of a second, how it's possible. Are our laws of physics wrong as if they are correct they should be applicable everywhere in every conditions. Please answer thihs question as answer in above link was not about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20056/2451

Comment: @Akash: The A to the other Q does answer this, for a slightly less brief answer see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faster-than-light#Universal_expansion