# How can we accurately tell distances of celestial bodies when considering superluminal expansion

Tags: special-relativity, speed, distance, redshift

If parts of the universe are moving away from each other faster than the speed of light relative to my position in space, how can we accurately tell the age or distance of other celestial bodies without knowing the maths and/or locations for accelerated superluminal expansion. Given we can't accurately predict the centre or point of origin for all mass if choosing to believe the Big Bang theory how can we tell distances and speeds when comparing a variable such as red or blue shift to a an unknown speculation and sources of newly created space time. It seems like our map of the universe could be completely different.

Order of searches lead to question at hand:

[https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/664251/if-light-and-gravity-travels-at-the-same-speed-then-why-light-cant-escape-the-gr#:~:text=As%20to%20the%20the%20other,rays%20will%20always%20move%20toward](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/664251/if-light-and-gravity-travels-at-the-same-speed-then-why-light-cant-escape-the-gr#:%7E:text=As%20to%20the%20the%20other,rays%20will%20always%20move%20toward)

[Superluminal expansion of the early universe how is this possible?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20056/superluminal-expansion-of-the-early-universe-how-is-this-possible)

[https://www.wtamu.edu/~cbaird/sq/mobile/2013/09/17/where-is-the-center-of-the-universe/](https://www.wtamu.edu/%7Ecbaird/sq/mobile/2013/09/17/where-is-the-center-of-the-universe/)

[https://www.wtamu.edu/~cbaird/sq/mobile/2013/09/17/where-is-the-center-of-the-universe/](https://www.wtamu.edu/%7Ecbaird/sq/mobile/2013/09/17/where-is-the-center-of-the-universe/)

Comment: I added an answer to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20056/180843 ... basically the "superluminal expansion" is just a definition artifact; at no point are there relativistically meaningful velocities that are faster than the speed of light.

Comment: Hi, I'm by no means any kind of expert concerning the subjects at hand. Have a small understanding though immense curiosity. please forgive if I'm naive to the concepts given, had to google a fair bit to save anyone from this response being full of un-needed questions. If velocity is the correct measurement concerning my question firstly do we only use redshift  or blueshift for velocity from our relative point in space, and by saying we should not be concerned about velocities relative to each other exceeding the speed of light do you not accept superluminal expansion?

Comment: There is no superluminal expansion -- or at least, there's nothing special about it. It's just an artifact of how we define "space" to correspond to the same time for every observer. If you're familiar with time dilation in special relativity, that should immediately sound suspicious! Part 2 of [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/504948/180843) discusses how the way we conventionally define space and time in cosmology would lead to superluminal speeds even in special relativity.

Comment: Excellent, thank you I'll have to read up on time dilation in special relativity, memory is hazy on it and concepts beyond me at times.